# What is the shortest way to write rangeOfString with list of names, dictionary, king james bible, etc?

Tags: iphone, string, search, items, names

This is embarrassing. I don't want to use coredata or text file. I need shortest way to write this code.

names ("John", "Matthew", "thomas", "isaac", "bible", "Mayan", "2012", more names)

This code takes extremely long and wasting too much memory, download time, and waste of space. Not recommend it. 10,000 lines.

```
 NSString *selectives = Name.text;
 if ([selectives rangeOfString:@"John"].location != NSNotFound) {
    //
 }
 if ([selectives rangeOfString:@"Matthew"].location != NSNotFound) {
     //
 }
```

Second. This code doesn't work. I don't what I'm doing wrong here. I'm lost. I need help!

```
    NSString *string = Name.text;
    NSString *NameMe = [NSString stringWithString:@"Jake", "miller", "thomas", "isaac"];

    if([string rangeOfString:NameMe].location !=NSNotFound) 
    {   
       // 
    }
```

Is there a better way to write this? How do you write? I'm not good at this.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you can use fast enumeration to shorten your code.

```
NSArray *searchStrings = // Set up your search strings however you want
NSString *selectives = Name.text

for (NSString *searchString in searchStrings) {
    if [selectives rangeOfString:searchString].location != NSNotFound {
        // Your processing here
    }
}
```

In the second case this line is wrong

```
NSString *NameMe = [NSString stringWithString:@"Jake", "miller", "thomas", "isaac"];
```

You aren't passing in a properly formed string. `@"Jake"` is valid, the rest, because they are outside the `@"..."` section are not.

Comment: What about split strings ","?

Comment: The method takes a string, not a number of strings with a split.